# gulp generate html file with jade via markdown json

Tags: gulp, pug, markdown, static-site

I'm using `gulp-markdown-to-json` and `gulp-jade`

My aim is to grab data from markdown file which looks like this:

```
---
template: index.jade
title: Europa
---
This is a test.
```

grab `template: index.jade` file and pass it along with other variables to jade compiler.

So far I've this:

```
gulp.task('docs', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('./src/docs/pages/*.md')
    .pipe(md({
      pedantic: true,
      smartypants: true
    }))

    .pipe(jade({
      jade: jade,
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/docs'));
});
```

I'm missing a step where json from markdown is read, and jade template filename fed to gulp.src before jade compiler runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gulp-jade` is the wrong gulp plugin for your use case.

- If you have a stream of templates that you want to fill with data, use [`gulp-jade`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jade):

  ```
  gulp.src('*.jade')
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(jade({title:'Some title', text:'Some text'}))
  ```
- If you have a stream of data that you want to render in templates, use [`gulp-wrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wrap):

  ```
  gulp.src('*.md')
    .pipe(...)
    .pipe(wrap({src:'path/to/my/template.jade'})
  ```

Your case is a little more difficult, since you want a different `.jade` template for each `.md` file. Luckily `gulp-wrap` accepts a function which can return a different template for each file in the stream:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var md = require('gulp-markdown-to-json');
var jade = require('jade');
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('docs', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/docs/pages/*.md')
    .pipe(plumber()) // this just ensures that errors are logged
    .pipe(md({ pedantic: true, smartypants: true }))
    .pipe(wrap(function(data) {
      // read correct jade template from disk
      var template = 'src/docs/templates/' + data.contents.template;
      return fs.readFileSync(template).toString();
    }, {}, { engine: 'jade' }))
    .pipe(rename({extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/docs'));
});
```

**src/docs/pages/test.md**

```
---
template: index.jade
title: Europa
---
This is a test.
```

**src/docs/templates/index.jade**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title=contents.title
  body
    h1=contents.title
    div !{contents.body}
```

**dist/docs/test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Europa</title></head><body><h1>Europa</h1><div><p>This is a test.  </p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: you are awesome! and I'm starting to love gulp... I migrated from jekyll to middleman, to gatsby, to metalsmith - and realised that I don't need any of those tools, gulp does it all.

Comment: aargh, gulp-wrap is complaining about extends inside jade: the "filename" option is required to use "extends" with "relative" paths, > 1| extends _layout

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `gulp-markdownto-json`. There if a lot of better solutions. For example:

- [Remark](http://remark.js.org/) — is an markdown processor that parse Markdown into AST-tree (in JSON format). It has support of YAML-frontmatter out of the box. By the way, there are a lot of plugins for different use-cases.
- [article-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/article-data) — extracts data from your markdown article without using of frontmatter. Personally, I use this package, because it helps me to write juse plain markdown files, with no worries about correct data in frontmatter. It just exracts data from markdown file and then you may do whatever: pass to the gulp-plugin, collect into array, analyze your articles, etc.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/denysdovhan/denysdovhan.github.io/blob/premaster/gulpfile.babel.js#L36-L74) how I use **article-data** in my personal blog.